# Hibernate unable to find identifier while saving Entity object to database

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc

I am adding a command object of type Employee to ModelAndView in my spring-mvc+hibernate app. The jsp has a simple form which will be used in 2 ways.

1) To create a new employee account

2) To edit an existing account (here the form will be pre populated. )

In the account creation case, the command object added is `new Employee()`. However in the 2nd case, I a load the employee object from the database and pass it as the command object. This populates the form without explicitly mentioning anything else.

But on submitting the edited form, hibernate can't find the identifier thus throwing an exception -

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested
exception is org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: The given object has a null     
identifier: org.kodeplay.springroll.model.Employee
```

The controller method mapped to this form action is this

```
@RequestMapping(value="/update.htm", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView update(@ModelAttribute("employee") Employee employee, 
          BindingResult result) {
        Map<String, String> errors = employeeService.validationErrors(employee);
        if(errors.isEmpty()) {
            //success
            employeeService.editEmployee(employee);
            ModelAndView mav = this.displayList();
            mav.addObject("success", "Employee Updated Successfully");
            return mav;
        }

        else {
            //show form again with errors
            ModelAndView mav = this.displayForm(employee);
            mav.addObject("errors", errors);            
            return mav;
        }       
    }

private ModelAndView displayForm(Employee employee) {
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("employee/form");       

        if(employee == null){           
            mav.addObject("command", new Employee());
        }

        else {
            mav.addObject("command", employee);
        }

        return mav;     
    }
```

Is it that @ModelAttribute annotated param in a spring mvc controller is not the actual command object passed but a new object of the same type as command object ? Is this normal behavior or am I missing something ?

And what would be the way to achieve this ? passing identifier as hidden form input ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

While adding command object,you should give the name employee instead  of command ie ModelAttribute name.